# Jenkins and maven-buildnumber-plugin

Tags: maven, build, numbers, jenkins, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I am using [maven-buildnumber-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) version 1.0-beta-4. This works fine on a project checked out of Subversion, but fails in Jenkins.

I assume this problem is due to Jenkins somehow removing the `.svn` folders.

I assumed wrong. Here is the error I got:

```
maven builder waiting
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-4:create (default) on project swift-core: Cannot get the revision information from the scm repository : 
Error!
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:146)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:124)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot get the revision information from the scm repository : 
Error!
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getRevision(CreateMojo.java:673)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute(CreateMojo.java:431)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Error!
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.checkResult(CreateMojo.java:753)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getRevision(CreateMojo.java:648)
    ... 30 more
```

I overlooked this:

```
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
/bin/sh: svn: command not found

mojoFailed org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-4(default)
```

There is no `svn` client installed on the machine, that is the true source of trouble.

Comment: How is Jenkins getting the code? Is it doing a svn checkout? You might try browsing the workspace to ensure that the .svn folders are there. Also, some output from the Jenkins console for a failed build might be useful.

Comment: Missing `.svn` could point to a `svn export` instead of `checkout` too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message shows that the command `svn` is not installed on the build machine. You can use `javasvn` as your providerImplementation with this configuration:

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>create</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <doCheck>true</doCheck>
      <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
      <providerImplementations>
        <svn>javasvn</svn>
      </providerImplementations>          
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

See http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/using-svnjava.html

If you need a **specific version of Subversion** (we're still using 1.5 here) you can pin to a specific version of svnkit too:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.5521</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Fantastic. I did not know you could use javasvn to be independent on SVN being installed on the target machine.