# buildnumber-maven-plugin: 'git' is not recognized on Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

My maven build is working fine on a local computer, but is failing on the Jenkins integration server because of the following error:

```
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --verify HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: D:\Jenkins\workspace\XXX\XXX
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: null at timestamp: XXXX
[WARNING] Cannot get the branch information from the git repository: 
Detecting the current branch failed: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

As far as I understand, it's because `git` isn't in the `%PATH%` of my Jenkins, which seems wrong `git --version` works fine within a terminal in the Jenkins server.

- According to this [Jenkins and maven-buildnumber-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412651/jenkins-and-maven-buildnumber-plugin),
  the work-around for SVN is to use the `svnjava` implementation. Is there the same kind of work-around for git?
- Any ideas how I can fix the PATH for Jenkins?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Configure the git executable in Jenkins with the absolute path...That should solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. In the tool section, the PATH for git is ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe```

Comment: Have you added the path for Git on %PATH% after you have started Jenkins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Jenkins was not using the `%PATH%` environment variable from the command line, but it's own `%PATH%` variable, defined in "configure" page of the "node". Adding git into this PATH variable fixed my problem.

Sorry for the noise.